# Typescript: Why is PromiseLike a possible type of this in an object in an async function?

Tags: typescript

I wrote this function but it throws an error and I don't understand why...

```
const createObject = async (): Promise<MyType> => {
  await Promise.resolve();
  return {
    async foo() {
      await this.bar();
      // do something else
    },
    async bar() {
      await Promise.resolve();
      // do something here
    }
  };
};

interface MyType {
  foo: () => Promise<void>;
  bar: () => Promise<void>;
}
```

Why does the function call in line 5 of `this.bar()` show an error? It tells me that `this` is either of type `MyType` or a `PromiseLike<MyType>`. The second possible type is the problem but I don't see in which case this might be a `PromiseLike`? Can't it assume that if that function is called, this is always an "loaded" `object`?

What is the most elegant way around this? Currently I am doing this (which is absolutely ugly and not understandable as the reader of the code):

```
await (await this).bar();
```

I also found out that setting the return type of the function `createObject` from `Promise<MyType>` to `Promise<any>` solves the problem but that isn't very accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `createObject` is an async function returning `Promise<MyType>`, a return statement inside it can either return `Promise<MyType>` or `MyType`. Either is valid. So when you directly return an object literal, typescript somewhat counterintuitively will infer that the type of the object is `Promise<MyType> | MyType`, and will type `this` accordingly.

There is no way to change this if the object literal is directly in the return. What you can do is use an intermediary variable. This variable will be typed independent and then it will be checked against the return type:

```
const createObject = async (): Promise<MyType> => {
  await Promise.resolve();
  let result: MyType = {
    async foo() {
      await this.bar();
      // do something else
    },
    async bar() {
      await Promise.resolve();
      // do something here
    }
  };
  return result;
};

interface MyType {
  foo: () => Promise<void>;
  bar: () => Promise<void>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAJQCcCmBDWKDyAjAViqAgLzxrQCeko8AFAJQBc8ACkuALYCW0KAPAFkKAFQoAHFAD54xaQG9g8MgHc0XBG048UAOlTRwAGwBuKBgG5F8QygT6ArodjMhoiTPgKlS8lRoAzcHAGTytvFTUEWAALHh0cNCQLMO8AelT4ABNweAMOW1jIAHN4FENeFIBfABoU32p4BKT6UPCfVXVWdm5ePRQDEzN6Szb4dKycvIKuYvholFQqq0qR+FRYeyRINf7HWEsVkBnMJH80UBR4V3FLr3hA8GYQ2S6tXj5jcC5MyVWmp5aL00PX4n2+v2AlSAA)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround and the explanation. Still don't understand why it can't figure out that the returned object can actually never be a promise since it is literally saying return {} without any Promise stuff.

Comment: @IceRevenge At the time the compiler needs to set a type for `this` it probably does not yet know if the type will end up being `MyType` or `Promise<MyType>`. It's probably a design limitation. You could report a bug on GH (but do search beforehand for a similar one). Maybe it's something that can be fixed if enough people identify it as a pain point or is simple enough.